# PullParserException while calling web service

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

Android is throwing `XMLPullParserException` while I am calling a web service (.Net) from my Android App. The Eclipse console is showing the following warning. I don't know how to solve this, please help.

> Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
>   attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.ksoap2.transport.KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE$1)
>   that doesn't come with an associated
>   EnclosingMethod attribute. This class
>   was probably produced by a compiler
>   that did not target the modern .class
>   file format. The recommended solution
>   is to recompile the class from source,
>   using an up-to-date compiler and
>   without specifying any "-target" type
>   options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will
>   incorrectly indicate that it is *not*
>   an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same problem as described above, I fixed it by compiling the source to the correct JDK in eclipse. Eclipse was started with the IBM JDK(1.5) for websphere development.

Solved it by closing Eclipse and start it again with the 1.6 JDK from Oracle